# Creating dynamic NSMutableDictionary query with multiple values

Tags: iphone, ios, templates, dynamic, nsmutabledictionary

I'm working on a project and I want to be able to handle some template type messages.  The template would contain something like:

```
"{{user1}} has just created an account"
```

I then have a data map that would give you a location within the NSMutableDictionary where the data is located:

```
"activity.message.status"
```

I then want to be able to query the NSMutableDictionary by splitting up that string, so that it becomes something like:

```
[[[myDictionary objectForKey:@"activity"] objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"status"]
```

I could make something as long as it was consistant on being just 3 strings, but some may be more or less.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: `[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"activity.message.status"];` should work too

Comment: Thank you Matthias!!  Your example is exactly what I'm looking for.  Could you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much easier than splitting strings into keys. Apples Key-Value-Coding allows exactly what you want.

```
[myDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"activity.message.status"];
```

> A key path is a string of dot separated keys that is used to specify a sequence of object properties to traverse. The property of the first key in the sequence is relative to the receiver, and each subsequent key is evaluated relative to the value of the previous property.
>
> For example, the key path address.street would get the value of the address property from the receiving object, and then determine the street property relative to the address object.
>
> [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: This is a good answer, and it's possible that this is what the questioner actually needs.  The ask was explicitly for nested dictionaries.

Comment: Matthias Bauch - Thank you!  This was exactly what I was looking for.  I'm sorry to have taken so long to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like,

```
NSArray *array = [@"activity.message.status" componentsSeperatedByString:@"."];
```

Which will create an array containing `{activity,message,status)`.

Now you have your array you can use for querying your dictionary.

```
[[[myDictionary objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:0]] objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:1]] objectForKey:[array objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[[[myDictionary objectForKey:@"activity"] objectForKey:@"message"] objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Good idea skram, but I wanted something that would basically be usable without me having to hand code the statement, as the array could be bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from your question how we should map `user1` to `activity.message.status`. For now I'll assume you mean that the template might contain a string like `"{{activity.message.status}}"` and you want to be able to parse that.

Here's one iteration that operates on an `NSMutableString` that can be looped until no match is found:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{\\{.+?\\}\\}"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string
                      options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSRange keyPathRange = NSMakeRange(matchRange.location + 2, matchRange.length - 4);
NSString *keyPath = [string substringWithRange:keyPathRange];
NSString *newSubstring = [myDictionary valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
[string replaceCharactersInRange:matchRange withString:newSubstring];
```

I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Great example of replacing the template locations, but I was looking at something to grab data from a dictionary, and then replace in the string, the value it retrieve.  Matthias' comment in my question post was what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about a (recursive ... cool) category method on NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object forCompoundKey:(NSString *)compoundKey {

    NSArray *keys = [compoundKey componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([keys count] == 1) {
        return [self setObject:object forKey:compoundKey];
    }

    // get the first component of the key
    NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:0];

    // build the remaining key with the remaining components
    NSRange nextKeyRange;
    nextKeyRange.location = 1;
    nextKeyRange.length = [keys count] - 1;
    NSArray nextKeys = [keys subarrayWithRange:nextRange];
    NSString *nextKey = [nextKeys componentsJoinedByString:@"."];

    NSMutableDictionary *nextDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self addObject:nextDictionary forKey:key];

    // now the cool part... recursion
    [nextDictionary setObject:object forCompoundKey:nextKey];
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it passes a quick desk check.  The objectForCompoundKey: retrieval can be written analogously.